# Unable to restore database from backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have taken a back from live database and trying to restore on my dev machine. But due to the different versions I am getting the following error. Is there anyway to sort-out the issue without touching the live database.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError:
>   The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.4297. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.4000. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching the error?

Comment: Yes I did but there is no info available about the specific versions.

Comment: 10.50 is SQL Server **2008 R2**, while 10.00 is **2008** - those are **NOT** the same; you **cannot** restore a 2008 R2 file onto a 2008 version - no way, no hack, no tool, no trick, no workaround - just won't work. Period. Either install 2008 **R2** yourself, or then you'll need to start using change scripts to get changes from the newer database down into the older one

Comment: @marc_s thanks. I will check if I can do update the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error tells you the problem, you cannot restore a NEWER backup to an older version of SQL.

I would suggest upgrading your dev machine to the same version, which is best practice.  Since this is a version newer, your best bet would be to do an in place upgrade on your dev machine, which would be fairly quick, I assume you are using Developer edition, which should not cost you anything extra.

Your other option would be to look at some of the RedGate tools to help you out.